# ag-grid cellRenderer failed rendering cell after value evaluation

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have an inline cellRenderer to modify in cell value as below:

```
cellRenderer: function (params) {
  if(params.value) {
    return params.value * 100;
  }
  return '';
}
```

I observed in the debug view that it is calculating the value properly. Please find the screenshot
[image]

But, the moment control moves out of cellRenderer it throws below exception:

```
ERROR TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
at CellComp.push../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/lib/rendering/cellComp.js.CellComp.afterCellRendererCreated (cellComp.js:582)
at Promise.push../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/lib/utils.js.Promise.then (utils.js:1543)
at CellComp.push../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/lib/rendering/cellComp.js.CellComp.createCellRendererInstance (cellComp.js:564)
at CellComp.push../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/lib/rendering/cellComp.js.CellComp.attachCellRenderer (cellComp.js:589)
at CellComp.push../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/lib/rendering/cellComp.js.CellComp.afterAttached (cellComp.js:100)
at rowComp.js:938
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at RowComp.push../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/lib/rendering/rowComp.js.RowComp.callAfterRowAttachedOnCells (rowComp.js:936)
at RowComp.push../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/lib/rendering/rowComp.js.RowComp.insertCellsIntoContainer (rowComp.js:554)
at RowComp.push../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/lib/rendering/rowComp.js.RowComp.refreshCellsInAnimationFrame (rowComp.js:460)
```

I have many other such cellRenderer those are working fine. Not sure what's wrong in this particular one. e.g. Below one is working just fine:

```
cellRenderer: function (params) {
  return params.context.formatDate(params.data.createdDateTime);
}
```

I am using `"ag-grid-enterprise": "^16.0.0",` and angular 6.

Comment: strange....may be it wants the string to return ? I have used cellRenderers on ag-grid many times as you have in example and it works fine.. 
try return ''+ params.value * 100

Comment: @Sh.Pavel thanks man, it worked. You saved may day!

Answer (score 2):

As per @Sh. Pavel's comment, it worked after updating it to `return ''+ params.value * 100`.

Important thing to understand here is, `cellRenderer` expects `string` in return, so that it directly appends it to the DOM.

As what you were returning was a `number`, proper `Node` was not getting generated (I guess). Which was solved by doing `return '' + params.value * 100;`.

Comment: Just to add, toString() as well helps to achieve same result. eg: (params.value*100).toString().